# Making two lists identical in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have two lists in python.

```
a=[1,4,5]
b=[4,1,5]
```

What i need is to order b according to a. Is there any methods to do it so simply without any
loops?

Comment: Will they always have the same elements?

Comment: You need to add another example with elements which don't appear in both lists. Else, a simple `b = a` will do the job.

Comment: @camelNeck Well, maybe `b = list(a)`, otherwise they will point to the same object, which could cause problems.

Comment: @Lattyware Yeah, of course. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: It's not really clear what the expected output is - for me. Could you give a few examples and what you would expect back?

Comment: @Lattyware Thanks for replying...I have two lists here say list1 and list2....Always these list will have same elements. But the order of elements in list2 will be different from that of list1. I just needed to make the list2 identical to list1...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to use `zip` to combine the elements of the two lists into `tuple`s:

```
a, b = zip(*sorted(zip(a, b)))
```

`sorted` will compare the `tuple`s by their first element (the element from `a`) first; `zip(*...)` will "unzip" the sorted list.

Answer (score 2):

or may be just check everything is perfect then..copy list a for b

```
if all(x in b for x in a) and len(a)==len(b):
    b=a[:]
```

Comment: PEP-8 recommends against one-lining stuff like that - it makes it much less readable.

Comment: @Lattyware Where does it say that?

Comment: [Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) - It is a *rather not* as opposed to a *no*, but in cases like this, I'd argue the actual action becomes hidden and it makes the code very hard to read.

Comment: @Lattyware PEP-8 argues against multiple statements, I don't think this is the case here, he is just "If all elements in b are in a and their lenght is equal then..."

Comment: @FábioDiniz The original post had the `b=a[:]` on the same line as the condition, that was my issue. Just as in the second example on in the link I gave under Compound statements. It's fixed now.

Comment: @Lattyware Okie dokie, didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make `list2` identical to `list1`, you don't need to mess with order or re-arrange anything, just replace `list2` with a copy of `list1`:

```
list2 = list(list1)
```

[`list()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-list) takes any iterable and produces a new list from it, so we can use this to copy `list1`, thus creating two lists that are exactly the same.

It might also be possible to just do `list2 = list1`, but do note that this will cause any changes to either to affect the other (as they point to the same object), so this is probably not what you want.

If `list2` is referenced elsewhere, and thus needs to remain the same object, it's possible to replace every value in the list using `list2[:] = list1`.

In general, you probably want the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sort b based on items' index in a, with all items not in a at the end.

```
>>> a=[1,4,5,2]
>>> b=[4,3,1,5]
>>> sorted(b, key=lambda x:a.index(x) if x in a else len(a))
[1, 4, 5, 3]
```